# Remove end line of a text file but don't remove two continuous end lines (blank lines)

Tags: linux, awk, text, terminal

I have a text (from a pdf) and I want to clean all the end lines but without the blank lines, the text has end lines and break lines, here is the text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillu.
```

To clean the end lines I use `awk` command:

```bash
awk 1 ORS='' my_text.txt > new_text.txt
```

But the result is a text with only one line. My original text has >2000 lines and when I applied the awk command I have a long one line and my text editor freeze.

I want have paragraphs without end lines, here the result that I want:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillu.
```

What conditions do I may use with awk (or another command) for respect paragraphs (no clean blank lines)?

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '{$1=$1} 1' file
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillu.
```

The constructs used above do the following:

- `RS=` - sets `RS` to null which tells awk to read input records
  separated by 1 or more empty lines instead of separated by newlines. This is known as "paragraph mode".
- `ORS='\n\n'` - sets `ORS` to 2 newlines which puts a blank line after every output record.
- `-F'\n'` - sets `FS` to newline so that, when `$0` is reconstructed by replacing each `FS` with `OFS`, tabs and chains of blanks aren't converted to single blank chars (the default value of `OFS`).
- `{$1=$1}` - updates a field (to itself) thereby causing awk to reconstruct `$0` from it's fields, separating them with whatever value `OFS` has.
- `1` - a true condition which causes awk to execute it's default action of printing the current record, shorthand for `{print $0}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below `awk` command to achieve your purpose:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"} {gsub(/\n/," ")} 1' my_text.txt > new_text.txt
```

**Explanation of the above command:**

- **`BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"}`** - It will set the [***record separator (RS)***](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnuawk/record-separators.html#record-separators) and [***output record separator (ORS)***](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnuawk/record-separators.html#output-record-separator) to double newline characters(i.e. `\n\n`) which effectively treats each paragraph (separated by blank lines) as a record.
- **`{gsub(/\n/," ")}`** - This will substitute each `\n` character within a record with a ***" "***. If you want to substitute with nothing then you can use ***""***.
- **`1`** -  Shorthand for `{print $0}`

**NOTE:** The above command is applicable for GNU awk. In case, you're requiring a solution using `POSIX` awk,

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1 && !NF ? "\n" : ""), $0; prevNF=NF} END{print ""}' my_text.txt > new_text.txt
```

You can find the implementation of the above commands below:

***[CODE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/DeepskyblueUnevenLists#main.sh)***

Answer (score -1):

`sed` hack.

```
$ sed -Ez 's/\n\n/\n\n\n/g;s/\n([^\n])/\1/g' file
```

set the expected line end to null (instead of newline). Triple the existing double newlines and remove all single newlines.